# Getting always Null value in onTokenRefresh method in MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am having a problem in getting token in `onTokenRefresh`  method

Following is my manifest file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <service
        android:name=".fcmService.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".fcmService.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Following is my `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService`

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

 Log.d(TAG, "@@ onTokenRefresh: " + refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    // Saving reg id to shared preferences
    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

}
```

}

and I am calling `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` in Splash screen like so..

```
MyFirebaseInstanceIDService myFirebaseInstanceIdService = new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService();
                myFirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh();
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: you are trying this in real devices or emulators

Comment: I am trying in real device

Comment: Are you sure the json file contains the same package name?

Comment: Also check if device has play services installed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the service method using it's instance like that, Because it needs to run on the worker thread,

You have to start the service and obtain the token using another service.

The token refresh is called by the FCM whenever the current token is invalidated,

Create another service by extending IntentService class,

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    try {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        // [END get_token]
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        // Subscribe to topic channels

        // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
        // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
        // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
    }
}
```

You can also start the above service from onTokenRefresh() method to avoid code replication.

Comment: Did you declare the service in the Manifest file?

Comment: How are you starting the service?

Comment: Intent myIntentService = new Intent(this,MyIntentService.class);   startService(myIntentService);

Comment: Can you check if the service is running by adding a log in the `onIntentHandle` method?

Comment: Check the google-services.json file and verify the contents

Comment: Download load a new one if you're not certain that you're not inadvertently modified it.

Comment: onHandleIntent is called but token value is null

Answer (score 0):

**onTokenRefresh** in FirebaseInstanceIdService is only called when a new token is generated. If your app was previously installed and generated a token then `onTokenRefresh` would not be called. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token, this would cause onTokenRefresh to be called.

try this you forgot to call this `super.onTokenRefresh();` in your  onTokenRefresh`() method`

```
public class FirebaseServiceId extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    public static final String TAG = "FirebaseId";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e(TAG, "Refresh token is: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
        Log.e(TAG, "Token2:" + token);
    }
}
```

**try this you can generate your token like this**

```
 String tonk = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
 Log.e("Tok: ", tonk + "");
```

Comment: I did this same in Splash screen and in  onTokenRefresh method, but no luck

Comment: @Shruti check updated ans you forgot to call ` super.onTokenRefresh();` in your `public void onTokenRefresh() {` method

Comment: @Shruti does your getting null token in Splash screen

Comment: **onTokenRefresh** in FirebaseInstanceIdService is only called when a new token is generated. If your app was previously installed and generated a token then onTokenRefresh would not be called. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token, this would cause onTokenRefresh to be called. @Shruti

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get token.
So the problem came from the fact that you can't use this line in your AndroidManifest.xml (inside  tag) :

```
tools:node="merge"
```

Firebase will not work in your app. At least, it's how I fixed my app to finally get a valid token!

Comment: By adding above line in Application tag i am getting error like : "Execution failed for task : app:processDebugManifest"

Comment: okk, remove that line and add `android:stopWithTask="false"` this inside `<service>` tag